Godot Game Crash After Splash Screen in Android
I created game using godot 4.2.1 and I'm trying to export it to android I exported the game using as both apk and remote usb debug. But the game crash immedeatly after the splash screen and it gives following error
05-04 11:18:30.543 27898 27898 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gamenew/com.godot.game.GodotApp}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize engine render view

